# compile not binding the attributes (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have been trying to refactor my code to make more use of directives to make the html more readable, I am trying to move some html in the compile method:

```
app.directive('fancyinput', [ "$rootScope", "SearchBoxData",  function($rootScope, SearchBoxData) {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: '<input tabindex="2" id="inputAnimation" class="anim-field" type="text" maxlength="70" spellcheck="false">',
    replace: true,
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

      tElement.attr('data-ng-class', "{'no-opacity': SearchBoxData.animating == false}");
      tElement.attr('data-ng-style', "SearchBoxData.font_style");
      tElement.attr('data-ng-focus', "decideToStop(); $root.searchFieldIsFocus = true");
      tElement.attr('data-ng-blur' , "decideToStart(); $root.searchFieldIsFocus = false");


      return function (scope, element) {
         // a lot of code in there.
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SearchboxController">
   <input fancyinput>
</div>
```

The methods in data-ng-focus and data-ng-blur are defined in a parent controller. I am trying to find a way to bind them to the html with the directive. The code above does not seem to be enough to do that. I am not sure what to do... Is there a way to completely build the html with a directive?

Edit: Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do:

http://plnkr.co/edit/YNYvQrqqvKqeBTrU2qfL?p=preview

Comment: Do you got some progress in this matter? I got a similar problem. [example of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jjz7/3/)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller yeah, I am not using compile anymore :). I have heard it cannot work due to how the `ng-*` directives are bound. It's mostly a timing issue. Overall, I don't really understand what compile for, everytime I tried to use it, I eventually found a way around.